# Not able to import file as module in pycharm

Tags: python

I am trying to import a function from a file `mydate.py` which returns current date to another file using Pycharm but Pycharm is not detecting that function of the file. To do so I am using the following lines

```
from mydate import curdate
```

but Pycharm is not able to find this function.

Comment: Are you sure that those scripts are in the same directory? Past code of `mydate.py` and show us how do You call this method

Comment: Does Pycharm give a Traceback error? If so please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46500476/edit) your question and include all of the text of the error

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark a folder as a source root.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-structure.html